# Spring Social - set application url on runtime

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-social

Application Structure:

1. APIs - Spring Boot, Spring Security, Spring Social.
2. UI-1 - Angular 5 - communicates with APIs.
3. UI-2 - Angular 5 - communicates with APIs.

Users are authenticated with Spring Social (Facebook and Google). Both UI project communicates with single API source. Now, on successful authentication API doesn't know where to redirect user (UI-1 or UI-2 app).

How to identify the source of authentication request and redirect user accordingly. This looks a simple use case, I am missing some obvious piece of configuration to identify the source of authentication request.

Looking forward for your suggestions / directions to fix this issue.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after spending a day I could make it work.

We have extended ProviderSignInInterceptor for a respective provider like Google or Facebook.

Here, you will be able to get request parameters in preSignIn; use these parameters values to set in session. Now you will be able to access these session variables in CustomSignInAdapter.

Anyone needs more clarity then please feel free to post a comment / question.